# NodeJS with Express and Mongoose trying to call one piece of middleware from another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to reuse code I have in two different NodeJS controllers but I seem to have not understood how the java calls work. The data comes from a MongoDB using Mongoose

I can call the picture code - findMyBoatPictures fine on its own but when I try to do so from the boat controller code - findMyForSale my trace is

trace produces this from NodeJS

```
 in boats findMyBoatPictures
 picture found records: 3
```

So the 3 records are found but after that it disappears somewhere and I cant see where

Any help would be greatly appreciated

What I am trying to achieve is that after having got the three records I want to add part of each record to the first of my boat records which were returned in the Boat.find and then repeat this process for each boat record

picture.routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    const picture = require('../controllers/picture.controller.js');
    // Retrieve all by boat Id
    app.get('/api/pictures/:boatId', picture.findMyBoatPictures);
}
```

boat.routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    const boats = require('../controllers/boat.controller.js');
    // Retrieve all Boats for sale
    app.get('/api/boatsforsale/:agentId', boats.findMyForSale);
}
```

boat.controller.js

```
const Boat = require('../models/boat.model.js');
const picture = require('../controllers/picture.controller.js');

// FETCH all Boats for sale by specified agent
exports.findMyForSale = (req, res) => {
    var query = { sellingAgent: "1" }; // fixed to 1 for testing
    Boat.find(query)
    .then(boats => {
        req.params.boatId = boats[0].boatId;
        var pics;
        picture.findMyBoatPictures(myCall, res, function (pics) { 
            if (pics) {
                console.log("find pics #1 result is " + JSON.stringify(pics));
            } 
            else {
            console.log("find pics #2 result is " + JSON.stringify(pics));
            }
            res.json(boats);
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("findMyForSale failure is " + JSON.stringify(err));
        res.status(500).send({
            msg: err.message
        });
    });
};
```

picture.controller.js

```
const Picture = require('../models/picture.model.js');
exports.findMyBoatPictures = (req, res) => {
    console.log("in boats findMyBoatPictures")
    var query = { owningId: String(req.params.boatId) };
    var orderBy = { sequenceNumber: 1 };
    Picture.find({ owningId: String(req.params.boatId) }).sort({ sequenceNumber: 1 })
        .then(pics => {
            console.log("picture found records: " + pics.length);
            res.json(pics);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("picture found error " + err.message);
            res.status(500).send({
                msg: err.message
            });
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**
The picture controller function `findMyBoatPictures` responds the request with `res.json`. It doesn't pass the control back to `findMyForSale` method from which it was called.

**Solution:**
If you have some code to re-use, abstract it in a service which is used by both of the controllers. That service can pass the control back using a callback and then the controllers can respond to the requests with `res.json` independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

First of all exports.findMyBoatPictures function accepts two arguments req and res but you are not initiating it correctly, this is what you should do

```
picture.findMyBoatPictures(req, res);
```

If u intend getting the value back u have to use a callback function i.e

```
const Picture = require('../models/picture.model.js');
exports.findMyBoatPictures = (req, res, callback) => {
    console.log("in boats findMyBoatPictures")
    var query = { owningId: String(req.params.boatId) };
    var orderBy = { sequenceNumber: 1 };
   Picture.find({ owningId: String(req.params.boatId) 
}).sort({ sequenceNumber: 1 })
    .then(pics => {
        console.log("picture found records: " + pics.length);
        callback(false, pics)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("picture found error " + err.message);
        callback (err)
    });
```

Then you do

```
  let pics;
   picture.findMyBoatPictures(req, res, function (err, pics) 
  { 
        if (!err && pics) {
               console.log("find pics #1 result is " + 
              JSON.stringify(pics));
               pics = pics;
           // Send ur response

        } 
        else {
             console.log(err);
            // Send ur response
        }
    });
```

You can even make it fewer lines of code if you use async and await